# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add' when adding data to json

Tags: python, pandas, normalization

Here are two examples of dataframes that I can have as input

```
first_df = {'data': {'historicalData': {'historical':[{'id': 52725940,'trades': [{'price': 99.94, 'size': 8}], 'product': None}, {'id': 52725941,'trades': None, 'product': {'price': 92.98,'executable': 18}}]}}}
```

```
second_df = {'data': {'historicalData': {'historical':[{'id': 52725940,'trades': None, 'product': None}, {'id': 52725941,'trades': None, 'product': None}]}}}
```

I want to add `{"price": None, "executable": None}` when product is `None` and `{'price': None, 'size': None}` when trades is `None`. So this is the code I'm using:

```
import pandas as pd

second_df = {'data': {'historicalData': {'historical':[{'id': 52725940,'trades': None, 'product': None}, {'id': 52725941,'trades': None, 'product': None}]}}}

historical = second_df['data']['historicalData']['historical']

[i['product'].add({"price": None, "executable": None}) for i in historical if i['product'] is None]
[i['trades'].add({'price': None, 'size': None}) for i in historical if i['trades'] is None]

output_df = pd.json_normalize(historical)
```

I'm receiving AttributeError: `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add'`

Expected output:

```
print(output_df)
id         trades  trades.price  trades.size  product  product.price  product.executable 
52725940   None    None          None         None     None           None 
52725941   None    None          None         None     None           None
```

How to resolve this and what is the best way to do when we deal with a huge dataframes please ?

Comment: Those are nested dictionaries, not pandas dataframes.

Answer (score 1):

These are dictionaries, not dataframes. To replace a dictionary element, just assign to it.

There's no reason to use a list comprehension if you're not assigning the result anywhere. Just use an ordinary `for` loop with an `if` statement.

```
for i in historical:
    if i['product'] is None:
        i['product'] = {"price": None, "executable": None}
```

Comment: Thank you for the correction and your help but I want to add value `{"price": None, "executable": None}` to every `None` key `product`. Your code is adding `product.price` and `product.executable` in the `output_df` but not keeping the column `product` as None in it. Please look at the expected output in my post above.

Comment: You can't have `product = None` and `product.price = something else`, since `product.price` is nested inside `product`.